# Missing init codes in .swift files

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, initialization, custom-cell

I have been trying to learn to do the UITableView Custom Cells and have been looking up examples on youtube. However they always come up with an error when I run them.

I was looking at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIRvqRzOa-s and I noticed that when they first created a new .swift file it had this code:

```
init(style: UITableViewStyle){
super.init(style: style)}
```

When I created my .swift file it did not have this in it. I am wondering if this is why my tableviews are not running. I am currently using Xcode 6.1.1. I had tried to just type the code in as well but that didn't work either. Anyway to fix this or is it a bug?

EDIT:

so the full code I used for maintableviewcontroller.swift:

```
import UIKit

var ArrayObject = ArrayData()

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ArrayObject.MyArray().count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:MyCustomTableViewCell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomTableViewCell
    cell.LabelForDisplay.text = ArrayObject.MyArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
    return cell
}
```

}

Mycustomtablecell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet var LabelForDisplay: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}

}
```

and ArrayData.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ArrayData: NSObject {


func MyArray() -> NSMutableArray
{
    var Arraydatas:NSMutableArray = ["Effect Works", "NPN Labs", "Alvin", "Varghese"]
    return Arraydatas
}


}
```

the error I was getting was "thread 1 sigterm"

Comment: Is that all your code? Don't you have a `class` around that? What is the error message you get?

Comment: No that isn't all my code. That was just what was missing from my code compared to the video.

Comment: Can you post your full code please? I'm on mobile and can't watch the video right now.

Comment: So I figured out the thread1 sigterm issue was because the initial view controller was not selected. But the Xcode still would not run. I redid the whole code again (just copy and paste to new project because I thought I may have played around with it too much before getting to the solution) and somehow it works now..no idea why!! But thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create an `UITableViewController` instead of selecting `File > New > File... > Swift File`

do `File > New > File... > Cocoa Touch Class > Class: MainTableViewController > Subclass of: UITableViewController`

This way you will have all the necessary code to start, no need to copy it from tutorials.

Comment: Thanks. I did open it in cocoa touch class exactly like that and not in a swift file. But the init code is still missing. Maybe it's the Xcode version the person is using is different to mine?

Comment: Swift started shipping with the first version of Xcode 6, it's not possible to compile Swift code with earlier versions of Xcode. When you create a class you get a free init(), you don't see it in code but it's there. You can make your own convenience init() but if you choose to do so and your class inherits from another class you have to also `override` your superclass init() and call super.